# How to efficient groupby two column and return each group's first row order by time_create?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a big table which used to record stock quantity, it is already order by time_create.

Now, I want to get latest all products stock quantity in each store.

Code:

```
select SQ.store_id,SQ.product_id, max(SQ.time_create) as last_time, SQ.store_product_quantity_new  
from stockquantitylogs as SQ 
where SQ.time_create > unix_timestamp("2018-08-01")*1000  
group by SQ.store_id, SQ.product_id
```

But this is very very slow.

So I wonder how to make my query more efficient.

PS: Does `SQ.store_product_quantity_new` get by `max(SQ.time_create)` ? I am not sure this,  just want to get `store_product_quantity_new` with`max(SQ.time_create)`

---

Structure

```
create table stockquantitylogs
(
  id                         char(36) collate utf8_bin default '' not null
    primary key,
  store_id                   char(36) collate utf8_bin default '' not null,
  product_id                 char(36) collate utf8_bin default '' not null,
  time_create                bigint                               not null,
  time_update                bigint                               not null,
  store_product_quantity_old int                                  not null,
  store_product_quantity_new int                                  not null
);

create index IX_product_id
  on stockquantitylogs (product_id);

create index IX_store_id
  on stockquantitylogs (store_id);

create index IX_time_create
  on stockquantitylogs (time_create);

create index IX_time_update
  on stockquantitylogs (time_update);
```

Comment: Table structure (with indexing details), with EXPLAIN statement results would be helpful

Comment: Tables are `unordered sets`, ONLY when you query that with an `order by` can you guarantee it will be presented in the expected order.

Comment: I think this would be more helpful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Deebster 5.6 I think

Comment: @Mithril please post Explain Statement results also. Also, considering that primary key is Char and store_id is also Char (instead of being Int), they will definitely have slower performance compared to using Int.

Comment: Follow the tag I added.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just use max() on a column and automatically select the other columns from the same row. In later versions of MySQL the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option is enabled by default, which means even attempting this query is an error (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

You need to figure out which rows are the ones you want, and then select them:

`SELECT sq.store_id, sq.product_id, sq.time_create AS last_time, sq.store_product_quantity_new
FROM stockquantitylogs AS sq
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT store_id, product_id, MAX(time_create) AS time_create
    FROM stockquantitylogs
    GROUP BY store_id, product_id
) AS sq_latest USING(store_id, product_id, time_create)`

Here we first select the desired (latest) rows with:

`SELECT store_id, product_id, MAX(time_create) AS time_create
FROM stockquantitylogs
GROUP BY store_id, product_id`

Then the outer query selects the rows to return by joining onto the matching rows from the inner results.

To make this perform well, you will need an index on the relevant rows:

`` INDEX `store_id_product_id_time_create` (`store_id`, `product_id`, `time_create`) ``

Note that I have removed your where statement - if this is required add it into the inner `sq_latest` query.